# Java Server вопрос по потокам

Tags: java

Добрый день всем .Давно не юзал Java и  на этом уровне . Уровень знания JAVA у меня - 0-1 = -1 причем в области Серверов. Но появилась задача где требуется собрать простой чат на JAVA - Client/Server. 
С клиентом все прекрасно , юзая GOOGLE собрал ее)) 
И сервер тоже собрал. Все прекрасно работает , пока юзер не вырубает у себя мой написанный клиент.

Привожу код Сервера

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new Server()).start(); 

}
public void run() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(10058,10000);
        while(true){

            connection = server.accept();

            System.out.println("Welcome to ISICA SERVER v0.1");

            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); // Слушаем
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); // Слушаем
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (String)input.readObject());
            System.out.println("Get message: "+input.readObject());
            output.writeObject("You send: "+input.readObject());
            output.flush(); // Закончить поток


        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace(); // Error

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace(); // Error
    //  run();
    } catch (HeadlessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //  e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

И так , когда юзер отключает у себя Клиент то автоматом вырубается сам сервер тоже. Как организовать код таким что бы Сервер не вырубался после того как клиент прерывает сесссию, отключая клиент.

Запускаю на UBUNTU - server.
Клиент на Mac OS.

Вот Код клиента , если требуется :)

```
public class Client extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    static private Socket connection;
    static private ObjectOutputStream output; // Output
    static private ObjectInputStream input; // Input 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Client("ISICA client v 0.1")).start(); 
    }

    public Client(String name){
         super(name);
         JFrame frame = new JFrame(name);

        // setLayout(new FlowLayout());

         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setSize(700,550);
         comp(frame.getContentPane()); 

        //frame.setSize(700,550);
         frame.setBackground(new Color(41, 41, 41));
         frame.pack(); 
         frame.setVisible(true);
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);





    }

    public static void comp(Container panel1){
                    /* Elements  */
         JButton button = new JButton("Send");
         button.setBackground(Color.green);
         button.setForeground(Color.black);
         button.setOpaque(true);
         button.setBorderPainted(false);



         JTextArea chatArea = new JTextArea("", 15, 100);

         JTextField message = new JTextField();
         message.setOpaque(true);
         message.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){

             public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
              {
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                    {
                        sendData(message.getText());
                        String msg = chatArea.getText()+"\n YOU: "+message.getText();
                        chatArea.setText(msg);
                        message.setText("");

                    }
              }

         });             

         button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(e.getSource()==button){
                        sendData(message.getText());
                        message.setText("");

                    }
                }
             });



                    /* End Elements */


         panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());  
         panel1.setBackground(new Color(41, 41, 41));
         GridBagConstraints p1 = new GridBagConstraints();


         p1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; 
         p1.weightx = 1;
         p1.gridx = 1;
         p1.gridy = 1;
         p1.gridwidth = 2;
         p1.weighty = 1.0;
         chatArea.setForeground(Color.green);
         chatArea.setBackground(Color.black);
         panel1.add(chatArea, p1);

         p1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; 
         p1.weightx = 2;
         p1.gridx = 1;
         p1.weighty = 1.0;
         p1.gridwidth = 1;
         p1.gridy = 2;

         message.setBackground(Color.black);
         message.setForeground(Color.green);

         panel1.add(message, p1);

         p1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; 
         p1.weightx = 0.5;
         p1.weighty = 1.0; 
         p1.gridwidth = 1;
         p1.gridx = 2;
         p1.gridy = 2;

         panel1.add(button, p1);



        // final JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
         //JButton b1 = new JButton("Connect");
         /*
         b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(e.getSource()==b1){
                    sendData(t1.getText());
                }
            }
         });
         */




    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true){
                connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.107"), 10058);
                output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); // Слушаем
                input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); // Слушаем
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (String)input.readObject());
                System.out.println((String)input.readObject());
                //return input.re;

            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace(); // Error

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace(); // Error
        } catch (HeadlessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void sendData(Object obj){
        try {
            output.flush();
            output.writeObject(obj);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //  e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Поправил и добавил. :)

Comment: Для сервера  `static private Socket connection;` сделайте не статик, и при каждой `Accept`  делайте объект `new`

Comment: Если не сложно , можете привести пример . На моем коде, либо другом . Буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае программа настроена на работу с одним соединением, или же другими словами - на один поток. Для того что бы решить эту проблему, нужно реализовать многопоточное приложение.
Я в свое время писал что-то в таком духе. Вот кода [проекта](https://github.com/VyacheslavMartynenko/NetworkLab2) (реализована часть с тайм-аутами).
Пример кода:

```
public class ThreadedEchoServer {

    static final int PORT = 1978;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
            }
            // new threa for a client
            new EchoThread(socket).start();
        }
    }
}
```

и

```
public class EchoThread extends Thread {
    protected Socket socket;

    public EchoThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.socket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        InputStream inp = null;
        BufferedReader brinp = null;
        DataOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            inp = socket.getInputStream();
            brinp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inp));
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        }
        String line;
        while (true) {
            try {
                line = brinp.readLine();
                if ((line == null) || line.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT")) {
                    socket.close();
                    return;
                } else {
                    out.writeBytes(line + "\n\r");
                    out.flush();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131377/socket-programming-multiple-client-to-one-server).

Comment: Спасибо огромное за приведенный выше код. Уже знакомлюсь.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не понимаю почему, но GitHub утерял последние версии приложения, по-этому придется описать словами более детально решение проблемы.

Comment: Наш Сервер должен быть настроен таким образом, что при подключении нового клиента - для него создавался отдельный поток, посредством которого мы будем общаться с клиентом (в вашем случае же мы имеем упор на соединение 1 к 1).

Comment: Понятно, в таком случае если не сложно, могли бы мне дать какую нибудь ссылку с примером простого сервера с потоками. Я тоже ищу в goolge, просто думаю вы более точно сможете мне дать ссылку на статью так как писали подобного типа код и уже знакомы.

Comment: Привел пример кода из схожей темы, детали тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131377/socket-programming-multiple-client-to-one-server

Comment: Огромное Спасибо! Думаю уже , не составит труда самому решить их приведенного вами кода и источника.

Comment: Рад был помочь, удачи.